# Custom tooltip CSS issue with the header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a tooltip using CSS but what I can't achieve is keeping the tooltip head into center. So if you notice it says £30.00 in the tooltip. If you write £300.00 or increase words in the tooltip the head of the tooltips doesn't stay in the center.

Can anyone help?

```css
.tooltip-card {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  background: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.tooltip-card-text:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;  
  position: absolute;
  left: 31%;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

.tooltip-card-text:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;  
  position: absolute;
  left: 32%;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 9px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.search-bolt-icon-map {
  color: #02b875;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-card">
<div href="#" class="tooltip-card-text"><i class="fa fa-bolt search-bolt-icon-map"></i>£30.00</div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">
```

Comment: Posted an answer, hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 31% and 32% are specific, and rely on the current width of the element. Instead, center the triangle with `left: 50; transform: translateX(-50%);`:

```css
.tooltip-card {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  background: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.tooltip-card-text:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}

.tooltip-card-text:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 9px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.search-bolt-icon-map {
  color: #02b875;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-card">
  <div href="#" class="tooltip-card-text">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt search-bolt-icon-map"></i> £30000000.00
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tooltip-card">
  <div href="#" class="tooltip-card-text">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt search-bolt-icon-map"></i> £3000.00
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tooltip-card">
  <div href="#" class="tooltip-card-text">
    <i class="fa fa-bolt search-bolt-icon-map"></i> £30.00
  </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">
```

Comment: So now it doesn't matter how long the value is inside it will always be in the center?

Comment: Updated. See for yourself.

Comment: if I try to update the color from #000000 to #777777 to match the color of the tooltip. The header border becomes thinner than the rest of the tooltip. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Usually this is caused by a line with a width of a single pixel, and it relates to the way the screen renders color. Try making the line wider.

Comment: If I try to increase the border of the line then the whole tooltip's border becomes different than the header, and it's quite visible. If you please have a solution can you update in the answer? :)